# Using definitions for key-val arguments

Tags: macros, graphics, key-value

I'm making a `\logo` command  like the `\title` command used for the title page. By default, I would like to use the `graphbox` `smash` key-val arg to be `tl`. But later on (depending on a users choice, say by a class option) I would like this to be able to be changed (to `bl`, for example).

Please see MWE below

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphbox}

\makeatletter

%%% this works, but I would like to change the default "smash=tl" value later on
%\NewDocumentCommand{\logo}{m O{4.0cm} O{tl} }{%
%   \gdef\@logo{\includegraphics[width=#2,smash=tl]{#1}}
%}


%%%%% \newcommand{\TitleLogoPlaceDefault}{tl}
%%% this throws secondoftwo argument has an extra } error
\gdef\TitleLogoPlaceDefault{tl}
\NewDocumentCommand{\logo}{m O{4.0cm} O{\TitleLogoPlaceDefault} }{%
    \gdef\@logo{\includegraphics[width=#2,smash=#3]{#1}}
}

% this also doesnt work, keval smash=tl undefined
%\gdef\TitleLogoPlaceDefault{smash=tl}
%\NewDocumentCommand{\logo}{m O{4.0cm} O{\TitleLogoPlaceDefault} }{%
%   \gdef\@logo{\includegraphics[width=#2,#3,]{#1}}
%}


\makeatother

%%% class option should allow one to change to \gdef\TitleLogoPlaceDefault{bl}

\begin{document}

    \logo{example-image-b}

\makeatletter
\@logo
\makeatother

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to expand your `\TitleLogoPlaceDefault` before forwarding it to the `smash` key. If you're using `\NewDocumentCommand` you could do this by using an argument processor that will expand the first token in the argument once.

But I'd not hard code the keys that are usable in your `\logo` macro, meaning I'd use a slightly different implementation. Also, two following optional arguments make for a poor interface (how do you use the second optional argument without using the first?).

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphbox}

\makeatletter

%%%%% \newcommand{\TitleLogoPlaceDefault}{tl}
%%% this throws secondoftwo argument has an extra } error
\gdef\TitleLogoPlaceDefault{tl}
\NewDocumentCommand{\logo}{O{width=4cm} m >{\ExpArgOnceProc}O{\TitleLogoPlaceDefault} }{%
    \gdef\@logo{\includegraphics[#1,smash=#3]{#2}}%
}

\newcommand\ExpArgOnceProc[1]
  {\edef\ProcessedArgument{\unexpanded\expandafter{#1}}}

\makeatother

%%% class option should allow one to change to \gdef\TitleLogoPlaceDefault{bl}

\begin{document}

\logo{example-image-b}

\makeatletter
\@logo
\makeatother

\end{document}
```

---

A more robust version, which only expands the first token if the default is indeed needed:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphbox}

\makeatletter

%%%%% \newcommand{\TitleLogoPlaceDefault}{tl}
%%% this throws secondoftwo argument has an extra } error
\gdef\TitleLogoPlaceDefault{tl}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__likethevegetable_logo:nnn #1#2#3
  {
    \cs_gset:cpn { @logo } { \includegraphics[{#1, smash=#3}]{#2} }
  }
\NewDocumentCommand\logo { O{with=4cm} m o }
  {%
    \IfNoValueTF {#3}
      {
        \exp_args:NnnV
        \__likethevegetable_logo:nnn {#1} {#2} \TitleLogoPlaceDefault
      }
      { \__likethevegetable_logo:nnn {#1} {#2} {#3} }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\makeatother

%%% class option should allow one to change to \gdef\TitleLogoPlaceDefault{bl}

\begin{document}

\logo{example-image-b}

\makeatletter
\@logo
\makeatother

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great answer, I like the use of an arg processor.